# Using a list or vector as input for a select statement

Tags: r, select, vector, dplyr

I have two data frames. The original, `df1`,

```
  Country Ccode Year Happiness Power
1  France    FR 2000      1872  1213
2  France    FR 2001      2345  1234
3      UK    UK 2000      2234  1726
4      UK    UK 2001      9082  6433
```

and `df1vars` which contains only a vector of a few column names:

```
1 Country
2 Year
3 Happiness
```

I would like to select from `df1` the columns in `df1vars`. When I, against my better judgment tried to do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- select(df1, df1vars)
```

To get the output:

```
  Country  Year Happiness 
1  France  2000      1872  
2  France  2001      2345  
3      UK  2000      2234  
4      UK  2001      9082
```

I got the message:

``` Error: ``ES1varselect`` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a list ```

Is there an efficient workaround to this aspect of the select statement?

Comment: Is `df1vars` a vector or dataframe?

Comment: Well it's a dataframe, but with one column.

Comment: Then you need to specify the column name. Try `select(df1, df1vars$V1)` assuming `V1` is the column name.

Comment: I then get the error: `Error: `ES1varselect$ES1varselect` must evaluate to column positions or names, not an integer vector`

Comment: @TomKisters `df1vars$V1` is `factor`, you need to convert it into character. `select(df1, as.character(df1vars$V1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both are `data.frame` then

```
df1[,c(df1vars$Colname)]
```

where `df1` is your `data.frame` mentioned in the question, `df1vars` is the other `data.frame` having following content:

```
    Colname
1   Country
2      Year
3 Happiness
```

Final output:

```
  Country Year Ccode
1  France 2000    FR
2  France 2001    FR
3      UK 2000    UK
4      UK 2001    UK
```